# How to create a gradle-based Java Project in Intellij IDEA 13.0.1 Community

Tags: java, intellij-idea, gradle

I want to start a empty project with Gradle in Intellij IDEA but it seems not so convenient as Eclipse does.

What I did is File->New Project->Gradle. And a project shows up but it's not completed (it has no src folder for example).

And I add `apply plugin 'idea'` in the build.gradle. When I refer to the All tasks in IntelliJ IDEA. There are no `idea,cleanIdea,ideaProject` for me to set up a IntelliJ IDEA.

In Eclipse+Gradle plugin, just create a new gradle project and everything is ready.

I want to know how to do that in Intellij IDEA.

Thanks

Answer (score 176, accepted):

When creating new Gradle project, select "Create directories for empty content roots automatically".

[image: New Gradle project wizard]

New project will have those directories.

[image: Gradle project structure]

Comment: hey, we all students here :)

Comment: FWIW In IDEA 14 Windows I am checking that box and still didn't get the directories until I disabled Batch Scripts Support plugin v 1.0.4

Comment: in 14 gradle asked me about creation after downloading some jars and stuff

Comment: In intelij IDEA 14 on OSX, it didn't immediately create the folders, but by the time I'd found this stack-overflow question and looked back in my project the src folder and its guts had appeared - so I think if at first it doesn't seem to work, just wait a bit before abandoning it.

Comment: IntelliJ runs some gradle commands after creating the project, so the files will not appear immediately.  After the project is created, you should see something in the status bar at the bottom of the IntelliJ window showing that it is running the command (or you may see an error if the command did not work...)  Once the command completed successfully the directories will appear in the project pane.

Comment: If I create the project of the same name after I deleted a project, my IntelliJ did not create src folder. Nothing in the status bar at the bottom as well. Then try to use [Refresh all Gradle Projects] button in the Gradle projects windows ([View] - [Tool Windows] - [Gradle]). I got my src folder back in this way!

Comment: @Dims did you find any solution for creating module with source directories ? I was told IDEA is better than Eclipse but frankly I'm finding it more complex and bad UX

Comment: @vikramvi I don't remember :) Somehow I am solving it each time :) I was not using Eclipse for few years and IntelliJ was definitely better when I switched. When using Gradle or other build automation tools, one should rely on their logic, so take time and learn how Gradle itself expects project to be organized and then let IDE adopt it.

Answer (score 32):

In latest IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition(2018.1), there's no `Create directories for empty content roots automatically` option available in `New Project` dialog. But we can go to `Preferences...`->`Build, Execution, Deployment`->`Gradle` and check the underlined option in the screenshot below.

[image]

Comment: THANK YOU. Every resource talks about the `Create directories for empty content roots automatically` option when creating a project, but no one mentions it's gone. I was doubting whether I was going insane searching for something that should be there or if no one has update writings in the topic. Never thought it would be the latter.

Comment: Its not called preferences, but settings. Maybe they renamed it to make it more complicated. Just bought IntelliJ for 200 bucks and still I cant use it for simple gradle-java project. I already configures 2 hours and still nothing works. 200 bucks and I am not able to use it for a simple Java Project, because src-folder is not created.

Comment: @mcflysoft I think you are on Windows and the namings are a bit different from Mac. I know your pains because I had the same. As for me I honestly don't want to pay 200 bucks for the Ultimate Edition. I sense that the Community Edition is already great enough. There are some tricks in having setup `gradle` project properly but it won't be too complicated.

Comment: Why is this not the default? I'm new to Gradle (and Java and IntelliJ) and spent too much wondering why I can create a new project from the UI but not add any classes to it!

Comment: this is the correct answer and should be the one as an accepted answer.

Comment: This option doesn't seem to be present when I look in the 2019 Community Edition