# No default folders created in new gradle project

Tags: java, gradle, intellij-15

I am following instructions at https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/creating-a-gradle-project.html to create a new gradle project. Before I can specify the gradle settings, a window opens where I am asked to fill in a groupID and an artefactId. This step is not in the description I linked. After I fill in the groupId and artefactId I can proceed to the next window where I check "Create directories for empty content roots automatically". However, this doesn't seem to acomplish anything. The project is created without the default folders 'src/main/java' etc. Did I miss some general settings or did I do something wrong during creation?

PS: I am using Intellij Idea 15, Linux version

**UPDATE:**
I managed to create new gradle projects with default folders. The initialization took about 10 - 15 seconds. The problem seems to appear only if I give the project and its folder a specific name, which was previously in use. This project was deleted from the Intellij project folder and also removed from Intellij project overview. So I tried to clear the caches and rebuild the index. No success. Does anyone know if Idea keeps references somewhere to previously, deleted projects?

Comment: Intellij can take some time to create the folders. How long did you wait? Also, Do you have Gradle installed on your system?

Comment: Have a look here, it might shed some light on your issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20648942/how-to-create-a-gradle-based-java-project-in-intellij-idea-13-0-1-community

Comment: Please see my update. I would really prefer to keep the name that I had in mind for this project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated in my question, the problem persisted only if the project was given a certain name, that had been previously used. The only workaround I found to "fix" this, is to completly delete Idea's home directory, i. e., /home/username/.IdeaC15 in my case. After that I started Idea again and could name the project as desired, although it had to recreate the index again, which took a couple of minutes.