# How to create gradle-based MODULE in IntelliJ?

Tags: intellij-idea, gradle

The following question [How to create a gradle-based Java Project in Intellij IDEA 13.0.1 Community](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20648942/how-to-create-a-gradle-based-java-project-in-intellij-idea-13-0-1-community) asks how to create Gradle-based project. And the answer works for me too.

But what if I go one level lower? Suppose I would like to have gradle-based MODULE?

Selecting `Create directories for empty content rules automatically` does not work.

Comment: **File | New | Module** does not work?