# IntelliJ IDEA 2017 create a "hello world" project with gradle build system

Tags: java, intellij-idea, gradle

I know there [were questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20648942/how-to-create-a-gradle-based-java-project-in-intellij-idea-13-0-1-community) similar to this one, but the answers don't work any more in Idea 2017. The [documentation doesn't](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/gradle.html) make it clear how to make idea create a simple console application with the gradle build system. I know how to create everything manually, but I would like to get it generated by Idea. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 3):

It's pretty straightforward:

1. [Choose Gradle | Java in the New Project wizard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pcm2c.png)
2. [Specify groupId/artifactId](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HXLgY.png)
3. [Create a new Java class in the `java` directory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4slAK.png)
4. [Run it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Q2fk.png)

Comment: But can I avoid point 3 and ask idea to do this for me at the project configuration step?

Comment: No, you can't. It takes a couple of seconds anyway.

Comment: You can reduce the time by using IntelliJ templates.  Create new class, type Alt+J or Cmd+J (depending on os) and type "main", it will bring up a template for java main class.  Press ENTER and it will generate the main method for you.  That's probably the fastest you can go from inception to execution.

Comment: @AlexC using `psvm` and `soutv` live templates is not much slower. I doubt user always needs to create the same hello world projects.

Comment: Search for main automatically brings up psvm.

Comment: This does not work... I can not run any classes even after "edit configurations"..

Comment: @Chiel please [contact support](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/requests/new) with the sample project and the screenshot of the problem.

Comment: Nevermind, it was because the module and the Main class were not specified correctly. Why does it not choose the correct module by default? In Netbeans this never used to slow me down.