# In Gradle Project for IntelliJ (2017.3), No Checkbox for Create empty directories for empty content roots automatically

Tags: intellij-idea, gradle

In the latest IntelliJ IDEA (2017.3), there's no checkbox option available for `Create directories for empty content roots automatically` when creating a Gradle project. But most resource materials reference this option. How do we enable empty content roots creation?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Referencing this answer from a different question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47089985/2067238

> In latest IntelliJ IDEA (2017.3), there's no `Create directories for
>   empty content roots automatically` option available in `New Project`
>   dialog. But we can go to `Preferences...`->`Build, Execution,
>   Deployment`->`Gradle` and check this option.
>
> [image]

Comment: Thanks! Very helpful!